# Dynamics CRM 2011 attachments using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011

Hi guys I am trying to figure out how to do attachments for an entity through WCF for my CRM 2011 project.

So currently I have MVC form that allows users to upload pdf files to my server. Now I want to have a WCF service that looks at the uploaded files and attaches them to the relevant entities/forms.

I am able to do basic CRUD operations on the entity by referencing CRM's WCF service, but not sure on the method to attach a file to that entity. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use code similar to that below to read in the appropriate file, encode the data and then create a new annotation which is attached to the appropriate entity. I have used late binding here in case you are using early binding for any reason.

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("pathToFile");
byte[] byteData = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
stream.Close();    

string encodedData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);

Entity annotation = new Entity("annotation");
annotation.Attributes["subject"] = "My subject";
annotation.Attributes["notetext"] = "My note text";

EntityReference noteRef = new EntityReference();
noteRef.LogicalName = "myEntity";
noteRef.Id = myEntity.Id;
annotation.documentbody = encodedData;
annotation.filename = "myFile.doc";
annotation.mimetype = @"application\ms-word";
annotation.Attributes.Add("objectid", noteRef);
annotation.Attributes.Add("objecttypecode", "myEntity");

service.Create(annotation);
```

Let me know how you get on,

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am getting errors accessing the documentbody, filename and mimetype properties of the annotation class.

Comment: Perhaps try accessing them via the Attributes collection, e.g. annotation.Attributes["documentbody"]. They certainly should be in there. This article confirms the setting of the attributes in question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328429.aspx. Let me know how you get on.